# Node.js: Nested setInterval()-Methods - inner one doesn't stop

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval, timing

I need correctly timed, repeated events in node.js. For having a higher resolution than the usual setInterval-method, I use `process.hrtime()`. The npm-module "nanotimer" ([NPM - nanotimer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanotimer), [Github - nanotimer](https://github.com/Krb686/nanotimer)) offers this with common methods like `setInterval()` and `setTimeOut()`.

The two timers should stop at the same time.

Code goes as follows:

```
var NanoTimer = require('nanotimer');

var timerA = new NanoTimer();
var timerB = new NanoTimer();

var index = 0;

timerA.setInterval(function(){
    console.log("A");

    timerB.setInterval(function(){
        console.log("B");
    }, '3s');

    if(index > 10){
        console.log("Stop Timer A");
        timerA.clearInterval();
        console.log("Stop Timer B");
        timerB.clearInterval();
    }

    index++;

}, '1s');
```

Output:

```
A
A
A
A
B
A
A
A
B
A
A
A
B
A
A
Stop Timer A
Stop Timer B    //correct up to here
B               //timerB continues forever, every 3 seconds
B
B
...
```

I can't find a way to stop the inner timer. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: node.js is extremely good at doing asynchronous callback based programming - what are you concretely using setInterval for (why the need for high precision timing signals)? Because I suspect what you're trying to use setInterval for, you might not need setInterval for.

Comment: you set many intervals for B (one per A execution), but you only cancle the last interval of B...

Comment: Im pretty sure you do not want to spawn B intervals inside the A callback. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Target: With the outer setInterval() I simulate incoming data with 2KHz over a SPI-interface (i iterate over a data array with `index`), with the inner setInterval, I push them via websocket to a client in a defined frequency.

Comment: @dandavis may have a point. I developed a (poor) workaround by unnesting them and exchanging time-sensitive data over global variables.